# nearby transits info by lat/lon

Tags: transport, masstransit, transport-stream

i have latitude and longitude of a location and i want to find nearby transit info of that location, just like how google does it on there google maps detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for Google Transit unfortunately.  You could probably scrape the output but this would likely violate Google's Terms of Service.

There are a few Transit authorities who provide APIs - if you want to cover a very specific area you might be able to go direct.  Have a look at [Programmable Web's Travel category](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=Travel).

Answer (score 0):

Jurisdictions forward their transit information as [text files](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html) to Google. Google then adds it to their maps. I'm not sure if transit is provided under the Google maps premium API. You might have to email them and check.

Using the google maps api, you can chose [the method of transportation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html). I'm not sure if that'll help you or not. I strongly urge you to email the maps api mailing list. You'll get a better response